# How to update the total number immediately when i put the value in the table

Tags: javascript, html, function, input

```js
function calculateTotal() {
  let rows = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let negative = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let row = rows[i];

    let quantityInput = row.querySelector(".quantity input");
    let priceInput = row.querySelector(".price input");
    let totalInput = row.querySelector(".total input");

    let quantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
    let price = parseFloat(priceInput.value).toFixed(2);

    if(quantity < 0 || price < 0){
      negative = true;
      quantity = 0;
      price = 0.00;
      quantityInput.value = "0";
      priceInput.value = "0.00";
    }

    let total = quantity * price;

    totalInput.value = total.toFixed(2);

    grandTotal += total;
  }

  document.querySelector(".GrandTotal").value = grandTotal.toFixed(2);

  if(negative){
    alert("No Negative Values!")
  }
}
```

```css
table,td {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', cursive;
}

th {
    background-color: skyblue;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

tbody {
    background-color: white;
}

.No {
    text-align: right;
}

td:nth-child(7) input[type="number"]{
    text-align: right; background-color: silver;
}

td:nth-child(6) input[type="number"]{
    text-align: right;
}

td:nth-child(5) input[type="number"]{
    text-align: right;
}

tfoot tr td:last-child input[type="number"]{
    text-align: right;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

tfoot {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.Button {
    float:right;
}

.GrandTotal {
    background-color: silver;
    font-size: 18pt;
    float:right;
}

tr:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.background-colour {
    background-color: skyblue;
}

body {
    background-color: lemonchiffon;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Book Ordering System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/book-order.css">
    <script src="book-order.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Book Ordering System</h1>
    
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Book Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="No">1</td>
                <!--Book Title-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Author-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Category-->
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="Business">Business</option>
                        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <!--Unit Price-->
                <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
                <!--Quantity-->
                <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
                <!--Total-->
                <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="No">2</td>
                <!--Book Title-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Author-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Category-->
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="Business">Business</option>
                        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

              <!--Unit Price-->
              <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
              <!--Quantity-->
              <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
              <!--Total-->
              <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="No">3</td>
                <!--Book Title-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Author-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Category-->
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="Business">Business</option>
                        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

               <!--Unit Price-->
               <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
               <!--Quantity-->
               <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
               <!--Total-->
               <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="No">4</td>
                <!--Book Title-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Author-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Category-->
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="Business">Business</option>
                        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <!--Unit Price-->
                <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
                <!--Quantity-->
                <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
                <!--Total-->
                <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="No">5</td>
                <!--Book Title-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Author-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Category-->
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="Business">Business</option>
                        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <!--Unit Price-->
                <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
                <!--Quantity-->
                <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
                <!--Total-->
                <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td class="background-colour" colspan="5">
                    <button type="button" onclick="calculateTotal()" class="Button">Calculate Grand Total Price</button>
                </td>
                <td class="background-colour" colspan="2">
                    <input type="number" name="Grand Total Price" value="0.00" class="GrandTotal" disabled>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to update the total value in the table immediately right after I input the value in unit price and quantity without clicking the button. The purpose of the "Calculate Grand Total Price" button is suppose to sum all of the total and display it in "GrandTotal" input field only.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Book Ordering System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/book-order.css">
    <script src="book-order.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Book Ordering System</h1>
    
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Book Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="No">1</td>
                <!--Book Title-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Author-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Category-->
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="Business">Business</option>
                        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <!--Unit Price-->
                <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
                <!--Quantity-->
                <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
                <!--Total-->
                <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="No">2</td>
                <!--Book Title-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Author-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Category-->
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="Business">Business</option>
                        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

              <!--Unit Price-->
              <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
              <!--Quantity-->
              <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
              <!--Total-->
              <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="No">3</td>
                <!--Book Title-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Author-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Category-->
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="Business">Business</option>
                        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

               <!--Unit Price-->
               <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
               <!--Quantity-->
               <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
               <!--Total-->
               <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="No">4</td>
                <!--Book Title-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Author-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Category-->
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="Business">Business</option>
                        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <!--Unit Price-->
                <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
                <!--Quantity-->
                <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
                <!--Total-->
                <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="No">5</td>
                <!--Book Title-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Author-->
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                <!--Category-->
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="Business">Business</option>
                        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <!--Unit Price-->
                <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
                <!--Quantity-->
                <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
                <!--Total-->
                <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td class="background-colour" colspan="5">
                    <button type="button" onclick="calculateTotal()" class="Button">Calculate Grand Total Price</button>
                </td>
                <td class="background-colour" colspan="2">
                    <input type="number" name="Grand Total Price" value="0.00" class="GrandTotal" disabled>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
table,td {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', cursive;
}

th {
    background-color: skyblue;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

tbody {
    background-color: white;
}

.No {
    text-align: right;
}

td:nth-child(7) input[type="number"]{
    text-align: right; background-color: silver;
}

td:nth-child(6) input[type="number"]{
    text-align: right;
}

td:nth-child(5) input[type="number"]{
    text-align: right;
}

tfoot tr td:last-child input[type="number"]{
    text-align: right;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

tfoot {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.Button {
    float:right;
}

.GrandTotal {
    background-color: silver;
    font-size: 18pt;
    float:right;
}

tr:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.background-colour {
    background-color: skyblue;
}

body {
    background-color: lemonchiffon;
}
```

This is my Javascript :

```
function calculateTotal() {
  let rows = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let negative = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let row = rows[i];

    let quantityInput = row.querySelector(".quantity input");
    let priceInput = row.querySelector(".price input");
    let totalInput = row.querySelector(".total input");

    let quantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
    let price = parseFloat(priceInput.value).toFixed(2);

    if(quantity < 0 || price < 0){
      negative = true;
      quantity = 0;
      price = 0.00;
      quantityInput.value = "0";
      priceInput.value = "0.00";
    }

    let total = quantity * price;

    totalInput.value = total.toFixed(2);

    grandTotal += total;
  }

  document.querySelector(".GrandTotal").value = grandTotal.toFixed(2);

  if(negative){
    alert("No Negative Values!")
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use change event listeners on the input fields.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Answer (score 1):

Delegate

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when the page hass loaded
  document.getElementById("myTable").addEventListener("input", () => { // any input - you can test if it is a number field if you wish
    let rows = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
    let negative = false;
    let grandTotal = [...rows].map(row => {
      let quantityInput = row.querySelector(".quantity input");
      let priceInput = row.querySelector(".price input");
      let totalInput = row.querySelector(".total input");
      let quantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
      let price = parseFloat(priceInput.value).toFixed(2);

      if (quantity < 0 || price < 0) {
        negative = true;
        quantity = 0;
        price = 0.00;
        quantityInput.value = "0";
        priceInput.value = "0.00";
      }
      let total = quantity * price;
      totalInput.value = total.toFixed(2);
      return total;
    }).reduce((a, b) => a + b)

    document.querySelector(".GrandTotal").value = grandTotal.toFixed(2);

    if (negative) {
      alert("No Negative Values!")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<h1>Book Ordering System</h1>

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>Book Title</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="No">1</td>
      <!--Book Title-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Author-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Category-->
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <!--Unit Price-->
      <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
      <!--Quantity-->
      <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
      <!--Total-->
      <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="No">2</td>
      <!--Book Title-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Author-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Category-->
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <!--Unit Price-->
      <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
      <!--Quantity-->
      <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
      <!--Total-->
      <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="No">3</td>
      <!--Book Title-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Author-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Category-->
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <!--Unit Price-->
      <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
      <!--Quantity-->
      <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
      <!--Total-->
      <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="No">4</td>
      <!--Book Title-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Author-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Category-->
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <!--Unit Price-->
      <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
      <!--Quantity-->
      <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
      <!--Total-->
      <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="No">5</td>
      <!--Book Title-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Author-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Category-->
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <!--Unit Price-->
      <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
      <!--Quantity-->
      <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
      <!--Total-->
      <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td class="background-colour" colspan="5">
      </td>
      <td class="background-colour" colspan="2">
        <input type="number" name="Grand Total Price" value="0.00" class="GrandTotal" disabled>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener on input of all your inputs elements:

```js
// Get all inputs
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
let grandTotal = 0;

inputs.forEach((input) => input.addEventListener('input', () => calculateTotal()))

function calculateTotal() {
  let rows = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
  grandTotal = 0
  let negative = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let row = rows[i];

    let quantityInput = row.querySelector(".quantity input");
    let priceInput = row.querySelector(".price input");
    let totalInput = row.querySelector(".total input");

    let quantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
    let price = parseFloat(priceInput.value).toFixed(2);

    if (quantity < 0 || price < 0) {
      negative = true;
      quantity = 0;
      price = 0.00;
      quantityInput.value = "0";
      priceInput.value = "0.00";
    }

    let total = quantity * price;

    totalInput.value = total.toFixed(2);

    grandTotal += total;
  }

  if (negative) {
    alert("No Negative Values!")
  }
}

function updateGrandTotal () {
    document.querySelector(".GrandTotal").value = grandTotal.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<h1>Book Ordering System</h1>

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>Book Title</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="No">1</td>
      <!--Book Title-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Author-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Category-->
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <!--Unit Price-->
      <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
      <!--Quantity-->
      <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
      <!--Total-->
      <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="No">2</td>
      <!--Book Title-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Author-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Category-->
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <!--Unit Price-->
      <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
      <!--Quantity-->
      <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
      <!--Total-->
      <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="No">3</td>
      <!--Book Title-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Author-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Category-->
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <!--Unit Price-->
      <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
      <!--Quantity-->
      <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
      <!--Total-->
      <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="No">4</td>
      <!--Book Title-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Author-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Category-->
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <!--Unit Price-->
      <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
      <!--Quantity-->
      <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
      <!--Total-->
      <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="No">5</td>
      <!--Book Title-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Author-->
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <!--Category-->
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="Please choose the category..." disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <!--Unit Price-->
      <td class="price"><input type="number" value="0.00"></td>
      <!--Quantity-->
      <td class="quantity"><input type="number" value="0"></td>
      <!--Total-->
      <td class="total"><input type="number" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td class="background-colour" colspan="5">
        <button type="button" onclick="updateGrandTotal()" class="Button">Calculate Grand Total Price</button>
      </td>
      <td class="background-colour" colspan="2">
        <input type="number" name="Grand Total Price" value="0.00" class="GrandTotal" disabled>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi I get what you did here. However, I am trying to only display the total for each row when a value for Quantity and Unit Price are entered by the user but not directly being showed in the Grand Total Price. The Grand Total Price is only supposed to be displayed when the user clicks the Button and the function of the button will sum all of the total for every single row only when the button is clicked but total for each row should still show when user enters a value for each row

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can just split up the function. Check edit :)

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with one function only?

Comment: You could check which element is passed. If it's a button you can execute that one line. However I would not advise this. Why would you want one function only?